# Order of powers

Tags: calculus, calculator

Which of the following is $a^{b^c}$ equal to?

$a^{(b^c)}$ or
${(a^b)}^c = a^{bc}$

This is probably a really basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html

Comment: Seems to be that you would first have to figure out $b^c$ and that is then your new exponent of $a$, so your first suggestion is what I would choose.

Comment: I cannot find the answer to my question in the link you posted.

Comment: I can't find the answer at that web page either. Here's a better web page answer: See *Iterated powers vs. iterated bases/exponentiation* at the Wikipedia page for [**Tetration**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense this is a problem of convention and notation. In mathematical literature the usual interpretation is the first one you mentioned. However if you write a^b^c  in a calculator/computer the answer might vary depending on the model/software as the "precedence rule" for powers is not universally agreed upon.

Answer (score 2):

It will be $a^{(b^c)}$ because ${(a^b)}^c = a^{bc}$ will yield a different result. For example:

let $a = 2$, $b = 3$ and $c = 4$.

$$2^{(3^4)} = 2^{81} = 2417851639229258349412352$$

while

$${(2^3)}^4 = 8^{4} = 2^{12} = 4096$$

Comment: Lol wow I need to learn how to use LaTeX

Comment: A good place to start for $\LaTeX$ is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) plus tutorials on the web.

Comment: Actually you only need to put dollars around your stuff... Thanks btw!

Answer (score 2):

It is $a^{(b^c)}$.  The usual explanation is that $(a^b)^c$ can be easily written $a^{bc}$

Comment: Also, I would also guess that $a^{(b^c)} = a^{b^c}$ makes more sense from the order of operations standpoint, where higher order operations take precedence over lower order operations (e.g. exponents before multiplication and multiplication before addition, unless over-ruled by parentheses).